# How can I derive the resultant of 2 bearing/elevation pairs

Tags: geometry, vectors

Say, for example I have a gimballed camera mounted on a metal plate, which is itself fixed horizontally to a boat.  I can measure the elevation and bearing of both the camera with respect to the plate and that of plate with respect to a global reference (say magnetic north and the horizon).

My question is, how would I derive the resultant of these two bearing/elevation pairs.

[edit]
In summary, I have two frames of reference, global and local, that share a common rotational centre. Each has it's own bearing/elevation component from which I need to derive a resultant vector in the same form.
[/edit]

Comment: Defining the bearing and elevation of the camera with respect to the plate is easy, because you simply read the angle of turn from each axis of your gimbal. But the metal plate is attached to a boat that can pitch, roll, and yaw as the waves toss it about; how do you define its orientation using just elevation and bearing?

Comment: @DavidK In this instance I'm assuming that the bearing is with respect to north and the elevation is derived from the pitch information.  I should also note that my example may leave a bit to be desired, since the plate and camera effectively share the same rotational centre.

Comment: You appear to be verbally specifying orientations that are usually described by three Euler angles, but you want to describe them mathematically with just two Euler angles. Even if your boat can only yaw and pitch, and never rolls, consider this: base plate with zero bearing (pointing north), elevation $5$ degrees; camera turned to bearing $90$ degrees right at elevation zero relative to the plate. The camera points due east with elevation zero, but its photos are tilted $5$ degrees relative to the horizon. Do you care that the photos are tilted?

Comment: Second scenario: camera again turned $90$ degrees to the right with zero elevation relative to the plate. The boat (and therefore the plate) pitches up $5$ degrees. The camera still has elevation zero (relative to the horizon) because it is pointing along the axis of rotation as the plate pitches up. But now the boat (and plate) roll $5$ degrees to port. This gives the camera a positive elevation. So unless it is _impossible_ for the boat to roll, you must know all three of the boat's Euler angles in order to know the camera's elevation under all possible motions.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, the boat does have three degrees of freedom. So the camera mount can pitch, yaw and roll, but the camera itself can only pitch and yaw on its mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll interpret the problem this way:

The metal plate is mounted in such a way that starting from an initial
configuration (level and "pointing" due north)
it can yaw (change bearing), then pitch (change elevation), 
then roll (rotate about the "forward" axis, which already has 
the given bearing and elevation from the initial configuration).
The camera, starting from a configuration that is parallel to the
plate and pointing along the plate's "forward" axis, 
can rotate around an axis perpendicular to the plate (bearing), then
rotate around an axis parallel to the plate and perpendicular to
the direction the camera points (elevation).

This is equivalent to mounting the camera in a five-axle gimbal
affixed to the Earth. To figure out the orientation of the camera,
we define a rotation matrix for each axle of the gimbal.
The rotation matrix is relative to $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes defined in
the initial configuration of the plate and camera;
I'll assume $x$ axis pointing north, $y$ axis west, $z$ axis up.

Using these axes, a single yaw/bearing rotation, pitch/elevation rotation,
or roll rotation is represented by a simple $3\times3$ matrix
such as the ones in ["Euler angles to rotation matrix. Rotation direction."](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441088/139123)
To find the effect of all the rotational motions on the direction the
camera is pointing, we take the initial configuration,
in which (I assume) the camera is pointing in the direction
of the vector $(1,0,0)^T$ (due north at elevation zero from the horizon)
and multiply this on the left by the appropriate rotation matrices:

$$R_5 R_4 R_3 R_2 R_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The order of application (which goes from right to left) is opposite
the order in which I specified the rotations earlier.
That is, $R_1$ is the rotation of the camera's elevation from the plate,
$R_2$ is the camera's bearing relative to the plate,
$R_3$ is the plate's roll,
$R_4$ is the plate's elevation/pitch, and
$R_5$ is the plate's bearing/yaw.

In the end you have a vector $(x,y,z)^T$ pointing in 
(usually) a new direction.
Since you don't care about the "tilt" of the image the camera takes,
just where in the world the center of that image is,
you can read the elevation by taking $\arcsin z$,
and you can read the bearing using the $x$ and $y$ coordinates
and an arc tangent function.
(In most computer math libraries there is a handy two-parameter
"arc tangent" function, usually called `atan2`, which makes conversion
of $x$ and $y$ into an angle easy.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this.  I'll try and code this up and see how it goes.  Matrices aren't my strong point, but I should be able to muddle by now that I have some direction.

Comment: One thing that may help (especially if you lack confidence in your matrices, but also to be recommended even if you felt very strong in matrix algebra) is to come up with some simple test cases that make easily-recognized rotations around just one or two axes; for each test case, input the five angles (mostly zero) and check that the resultant bearing and elevation is what you expected. I do that sort of testing whenever I can.

Comment: I'll model something in pari/gp first and get it running there.  At least I have something to go on now, which is a lot more than I had before.